# Handling clearing a view component in React Or Vuejs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vue-component

I have a container component that handle all the business logic, ajax, data etc.

It has children components that he passes data and methods as props.

So for this question there is a "CommentForm" component that gets a prop as the function to call when submitted.

Now all works good as the child component calls that method with the data but now I have 2 options:

- data was good, so clear the input of the component
- data was bad, show an error

Second option is easy...

but first one, how do I tell the child component to clear its content,
do I need to create another prop for it, or is it another good way?

** this code is an example of my code in Vue.js but this is general question like for react

```js
let Vue = require('vue');


ParentComponent = Vue.extend({

    template: `<div>
                <CommentForm submitted="myFucntion"></CommentForm>
              </div>`,
    methods: {
      myFucntion: function(text) {
        //whatever
        //but on sucess I want to clear the child component
      }
    }
  };
                         
let Vue = require('vue');


CommentForm = Vue.extend({
    props: {
        submitted: {
            type: Function,
            required: true
        }
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            text: ''
        }
    },
    template: `<div>
                <input type="text" v-model="text" />
                <button @click="submitted(text)" />
              </div>`
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering more for react here but the same logic should apply to Vue. You probably want the Parent component to own the value of the child's input, either by keeping in Parent state or by storing it in a flux/redux-type implementation. What you would do in React is have the Parent pass in the `value` to the child, as well as an `onChange` callback. When the child component detects a change, it fires the passed in `onChange`, and the Parent component updates its own internal state or fires a flux action if you're using a flux like implementation. That way, on successful submission the parent can clear the prop and pass it down to the child.

Any other method to do this will probably end up being sloppy because you'd need to either duplicate state between parent and child, or have the parent somehow reach in and call internal functions of the child, which is pretty hacky. Hope that helps!

Comment: so you are saying to pass a state variable to the child as a prop and give it 2 way binding?

Comment: I'm not sure if this technically is 2 way binding or not, but yes this is a very common pattern for simple cases like this. For a more complex case, it would make sense to store state in a flux or redux state object and have the child component fire events to change it.

Comment: well yes sure, in react you have that. but in vue it is synced in 2 way binding.

Comment: Oh, sorry! Perhaps there's a cleaner solution in Vue

Comment: If I have more components in that container like: add comment, add like, add new post.... so in your idea, I need to keep track of all that data in that big container and pass it down to all the child components...

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can be more help without more experience in Vue. My answer makes sense for the react ecosystem but I'm less sure about parent/child best practices in Vue

Comment: Well that's OK, the comment above relates to react

Answer (score 1):

The documentation has a section on [Parent-child component communication](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Parent-Child-Communication).

You could reference the child component from the parent with `this.$children`, though it's not recommended. Alternatively, you could send a custom event from the parent with `this.$broadcast` and have a handler in the child for that event.

Parent:

```
methods: {
  // ...
  clearData: function() {
    this.$broadcast('clear-data')
  }
}
```

Child:

```
events: {
  'clear-data': function() {
    this.data = ''
  }
}
```